Why does my keyboard keep registering imaginary key presses?
I'm running a Windows 10 Gateway laptop, about 3-4 years old. Had this bug occur where the End key is being triggered seemingly at random. Happens even when Num Lock is on. Occurrence rate is totally random, sometimes happening in one isolated event, and other times happening countless times in quick succession.
I already have uninstalled/reinstalled the drivers and that did nothing. Cleaned the keyboard and that did nothing.
My best guesses are that:

It's a software bug.
There's a short-circuit somewhere in the physical keyboard.

What methods would you all recommend to:

Figure out the nature of the issue?
Fix the problem?


Boot any Linix live session (e.g. Ubuntu). If the problem persists it's definitely hardware.

@ChanganAuto you mean (for example) insert the install media and run off the disc? Or like a VM? or, will either do? Thanks.

Linux Live means boot from USB or optical disk and "try" the operating system, which is an entry choice that is NOT install Ubuntu, in this example. It's a great troubleshooting method. ChaganAuto would do well to make this an answer.

@fred_dot_u Thanks for clarifying, I'll give that a go. In the event that it isn't a hardware problem, what would you recommend to look further into?

have you tried any other keyboard?

@JagratSingh I have not... I could not find a way to disable the built-in keyboard (again, this is a laptop). It's probably somewhere in the settings. The issue is also dormant ATM, so I don't wonder if humidity is playing a part or something.

In my case it was a hardware issues and the easiest way to know it is an hardware issue, you can use onscreen keyboard and if the keys in On-screen keyboard works without any random key-presses then it's a hardware problem.
(make sure to disable the physical driver while using On-screen keyboard)
(Settings>Accessibility>Keyboard )
